# Por que o front do webview em Objective-C se comporta diferente do navegador Safari no iPAD?

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, safari, ipad

Existe alguma forma de deixar ambos compatíveis na visualização.

Versão do IOS: 9.3.5
iPad 3: modelo A1416

Comment: Consegue descrever melhor quais são exatamente as diferenças a que se refere? E deixar compatíveis em relação ao quê?

Comment: Há várias diferenças, é justamente isso que gostaria de entender, pois ao meu ver, as duas versões são completamente diferentes, um exemplo disso é o iframe, que não funciona corretamente na webview, o touch muda totalmente de comportamento, a tela fica elástica e se mexe quando arrasta o touch por exemplo...